# Change laravel new project directory

Tags: laravel-4

Just installed laravel globally on OS X 10.9 and can create new projects via terminal using "laravel new projectName"

Tho, there's one problem, new project is created in my user directory, but I would like it to be created in my WAMP directory instead - "Applications/AMPPS/www/".

Is it possible to change it?

EDIT: Installed laravel 4.2 thru this comand: composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1" found in http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED. open terminal in specific folder, because "laravel new" doesnt know where is your localhost, right?

How to open terminal in specific folder: http://lifehacker.com/launch-an-os-x-terminal-window-from-a-specific-folder-1466745514